# Why am I getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export" error message in my vanilla JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, import, export, syntax-error

I have a vanilla JavaScript project.
I'm trying to export 2 functions from one file and import them into another.
However, I got the below error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: anchor_b
```

Below are the contents of the 2 files:

**File 1 (anchors.js)**

```
let anchor_a = () => "abcd1234";
let anchor_b = () => "xyz789";

export default { anchor_a, anchor_b };
```

**File 2**

```
import { anchor_a, anchor_b } from "./anchors.js";
console.log(anchor_a());
console.log(anchor_b());
```

Why isn't the code working and how do I make it work?

Comment: You want to use `export { anchor_a, anchor_b };`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't destructure a default export as part of an import declaration.

> Note: import { x, y } from "mod" is not equivalent to import defaultExport from "mod" and then destructuring x and y from defaultExport. Named and default imports are distinct syntaxes in JavaScript modules. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

What you can do instead is either first import the `anchors` and then destructure the object, like so:

```js
// anchors.js
let anchor_a = () => "abcd1234";
let anchor_b = () => "xyz789";

export default { anchor_a, anchor_b };
```

```js
// File 2
import anchors from "anchors.js";
let { anchor_a, anchor_b } = anchors;
```

Or alternatively use named imports (**preferred solution**):

```js
// anchors.js
export let anchor_a = () => "abcd1234";
export let anchor_b = () => "xyz789";
```

```js
// File 2
import { anchor_a, anchor_b } from "anchors.js";
```